# TeeChart Left Axis Label MisAligned

Tags: delphi, teechart

How can you get the vertical (left or right) axis label to align with the major tick mark when the label angle is 90 or 270?

You can set it in the chart editor under Chart|Axis|Left (or Right|Labels|Options - Position: set to "After Tick".  And this would be great if the property change was saved.  However, it is not.

I could do this in code if I knew what the property name was and the property attributes were.

Comment: Post a screenshot to an image sharing site, add the link to the question and we'll inline it.

Comment: Tried posting image to a "sharing" site.  Too much work.  Forget it.

Comment: It's no effort at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is *TChartAxis.Texts.Position* of [TAxisLabelsPosition](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TAxisLabelsPosition.html) type, for example:

```
  Chart1.Axes.Left.Texts.Position:=lpAtTick;
```